# Getting back the original curve having only the curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, plane-curves

More specifically, I'm trying to prove that all plane curves with curvature $k(s) = \cfrac{1}{as + b}$ are logarithmic spirals and trying to describe all the ones such that $k(s) = \cfrac{1}{\cosh(s)}$. I'm aware that this might be done with integrals (there is a constructive proof that all plane curves can be reparameterized by arclength that I thought could help me, but it turns out to be far too complicated). I thought about solving the following system of differential equations, but it didn't get me anywhere:

$x'' = -ky'$

$y'' = kx'$

Any ideas on how to do this an easier way (or even how I mentioned above, if there is something I'm missing and it's easier than I'm making it out to be)? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Should it not be $y'' = kx'$? After all, ${\bf T}' = \kappa{\bf N}$. If ${\bf T} = (x',y')$ then ${\bf N} = (-y',x')$. [Here prime denotes differentiation wrt arc-length]

Comment: @Matheus Andrade They are different intrinsic equations and naturally different curves.

Comment: @FlybyNight Actually, you're right. I've corrected the mistake.

Comment: @Narasimham I know they're different curves, I'm trying to fllow a process to find their parametrization for each one. The first exercise is to prove that $k(s) = \cfrac{1}{as + b}$ implies $\alpha(s)$ is a logarithmic spiral, and the other refers to the other curvature.

Comment: @achillehui Are you saying that the solution to my problem is a direct consequence of that theorem? If so, I can't understand how. I know that the curves being uniquely determined by their curvature follows from the fact that the system of differential equations above has unique solutions (the theorem you mentioned), but I can't see how that helps me describe those solutions in this specific case..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the second curve ( the first one is quite different) taking $\phi$ as slope and integrate

$$ \kappa = \frac{d \phi}{ds} = 1/\cosh s ; \, \phi = \tan^{-1}(\sinh s) + c ; \, \tan \phi =  \sinh s +c_1 \tag 1 $$
where the constant vanished when we started curve along x-axis as initial condition $\phi_0 = 0 ,\tag 2 $ then from 1)

$$ \sin \phi = \tanh s\, ; \cos \phi = sech s \, \tag 3 $$

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy/ds}{dx/ds} = \frac{\sin \phi}{\cos \phi} = \frac{\tanh s}{sech \,s} \tag4 $$

Integrate numerator and denominator separately after setting an arbitrary coefficient $a$

$$ x = \int  a sech s ds\, ; y= a \,\int  \tanh s ds \, \tag 5 $$

$$ x = a \tan^{-1} ( \sinh s ) ,\, y =a  \log(\cosh s) \tag  6 $$

where I took initial value translations as zero. This is the required parametrization.

The curve is visualized, it has vertical asymptote at $ x= \pi a/2. $

Eliminating arc length $s$ between $x,y$ we get a special gravity hanging chain whose formulation may be recognized as a ***chain of uniform strength,***

$$ y = log \,sec (x/a) \tag 7 $$

a sort of "deep" catenary, where $a$ is specific strength of material.

[image]

Proceeding along similar lines parametrization of first curve can be likewise established... in the following way:

EDIT1:

For first curve we integrate the natural equation. Wlog we can set $b=0, a=1$; it only means we starting at a more convenent point elsewhere, to another $1$ parameter, geometrically similar figure or curve. By integrating with proper boundary conditions, setting $c=0$, we get

$$ \kappa = \frac{d \phi}{ds} = 1/s ; \, \phi = \log  \frac{s}{c}; \tag 8 $$

$$ \frac {dx}{ds} = \cos \log \frac{s}{c};\, \frac {dx}{ds} = \sin\log \frac{s}{c} \tag 9 $$

$$ (x,y) = \frac {s}2 (  \cos \log(s/c) + \sin \log(s/c) ,\,- \cos \log(s/c) + \sin \log(s/c) ) \tag {10} $$

[image]

This curve gets flatter when you let $s \rightarrow \infty$ as expected.

Comment: A deep and thorough answer, thank you. I'm having a tough time applying what you did to the first curve, though: I get  $\phi = \cfrac{\log(ax+b)}{a} + c$. Taking the cosine and sine of that doesn't work as well as it did for the second curve. Is there anything I'm missing here? Also, what program did you use to make those images?

Comment: Also, I'm not seeing how you got to equation (4)

Answer (score 1):

If a plane curve $$\gamma:\quad s\mapsto\bigl(x(s),y(s)\bigr)$$
is parametrized with respect to arc length then
$$\dot x(s)=\cos\theta(s),\quad \dot y(s)=\sin\theta(s)\ ,\tag{1}$$
whereby $s\mapsto\theta(s)$ denotes the changing polar angle of the unit tangent vector ${\bf t}(s)=\bigl(\dot x(s), \dot y(s)\bigr)$. The curvature $\kappa(s)$ then is the speed with which ${\bf t}(s)$ is turning counterclockwise, i.e.,
$$\kappa(s)=\dot\theta(s)\ .$$
In your case $\kappa$ is given as a function of $s$, and the indefinite integral 
$\int \kappa(s)\>ds$ gives $s\mapsto\theta(s)$ up to an additive constant. Changing this constant will just rotate $\gamma$ as a rigid object in the plane. When $\theta(s)$ has been determined a second integration using $(1)$ will then give $s\mapsto x(s)$ and $s\mapsto y(s)$, whereby these functions are of course only determined up to a translation.

Comment: That's what I meant when I was referencing "a constructive prove that turns out to be far too complicated". Doing all of that for my first example, the following is the curve below, which seems terribly ugly, hence my desire for something simpler. Thank you, though!

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=curvature+of+(+(((a+x+%2B+b)+(sin((log(a+x+%2B+b))%2Fa)+%2B+a+cos((log(a+x+%2B+b))%2Fa)))%2F(a%5E2+%2B+1)),+((a+x+%2B+b)+(a+sin((log(a+x+%2B+b))%2Fa)+-+cos((log(a+x+%2B+b))%2Fa)))%2F(a%5E2+%2B+1))

Answer (score 1):

If you use this curvature, well, it will be a messy. So we can translate the curve $\alpha$ assuming that $\alpha (1) = (1,1)$, $\alpha'(1)=(0,1)$ and take $\kappa(s) = \frac{1}{s}$, $s>0$.

Take
$$\theta(s) = \int_1^s \frac{1}{t} \mathrm{d}t = \ln(|s|)$$
and $\alpha(1) = (1,1) \Rightarrow s_0=x_0=y_0=1$.

So
$$x(s) = 1 \int_1^s \cos (\ln(|t|)+\lambda) \mathrm{d}t \Rightarrow x'(s) = \cos(\ln(|s|) + \lambda).$$
But $\alpha(1) = (0,1) \Rightarrow x'(1)=0$ and $y'(1) = 1$.
So
$$x'(1) = 0 \Rightarrow \cos(\lambda)=0 \Rightarrow \lambda = \frac{\pi}{2} + k \pi; \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}.$$
Taking $k=0$ we have $\lambda = \frac{\pi}{2}$;
So
$$x(s) = 1 + \int_1^s \cos \left( \ln (|t|) + \frac{\pi}{2} \right) dt = 1 - \int_1^s \sin ( \ln (|t|)) dt$$
$$= 1- \left( t \sin (\ln(|t|))|_1^s - \int_1^s \cos(\ln(|t|)) \mathrm{d}t\right) = 1 - s \cdot \sin (\ln(|s|)) + (t \cdot \cos (\ln(|s|))|_1^s - \int_1^s - \sin (\ln(|t|))\mathrm{d}t,$$
ie
$$1 - \int_1^s \sin (\ln(|t|))\mathrm{d}t = 1 - s \cdot \sin (\ln(|s|)) + (t \cdot \cos (\ln(|s|))|_1^s - \int_1^s - \sin (\ln(|t|))\mathrm{d}t \Rightarrow$$
$$\int_1^s \sin (\ln(|t|))\mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{s}{2} (\sin(\ln(|s|)) - \cos(\ln(|s|))).$$
Therefore,
$$x(s) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{s}{2}(\sin(\ln(|s|)) - \cos(\ln(|s|))).$$
In the same way
$$y(s) = 1 + \int_1^s \sin \left( \ln(|t|) + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) \mathrm{d}t$$
where $y'(1) = 1$ and $y(s) = 1 + \int_1^s \cos(\ln(|t|))\mathrm{d}t$.

Integrating two times by parts we have
$$y(s) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{s}{2} (\sin(\ln(|s|)) + \cos (\ln(|s|))).$$
But
$$\begin{cases}
 \cos(\ln(|s|)) + \sin (\ln(|s|)) = \sqrt{2} \sin \left(\ln(|s|) + \frac{\pi}{4} \right)\\
 \sin(\ln(|s|)) - \cos (\ln(|s|)) = -\sqrt{2} \cos \left(\ln(|s|) + \frac{\pi}{4} \right)\\
\end{cases}$$
So
$$x(s) = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} s \cos \left(\ln(|s|) + \frac{\pi}{4}\right);$$
$$y(s) = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} s \sin \left(\ln(|s|) + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$
Let $u = \frac{\pi}{4}$ implies $|s| = e^{u-\frac{\pi}{4}}$ and $s =e^{u-\frac{\pi}{4}}$ by $s>0$.

Taking the reparametrization $\beta(u) = \alpha \circ \psi(u)$ where $\psi (u) = e^{u-\frac{\pi}{4}}$. So

$$\beta(u) = (x(\psi(u)),y(\psi(u))) = \left( \frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} e^{u-\frac{\pi}{4}} \cdot \cos (u), \frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} e^{u-\frac{\pi}{4}} \cdot \sin (u)\right)$$

$$\beta(u) = \left( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} \right) + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}} (e^u \cos (u), e^u \sin (u)),$$
which is a logarithmic spiral.